# YAML-loader in react returns only file path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, yaml

I got the following in my webpack config

```json
{
   test: /\.ya?ml$/,
   use: 'yaml-loader'
}
```

In one of my TSX files I import a YAML file:

```
import mydata from './data.yaml'
...

console.log(mydata)
```

data.yaml content is

```
text: hello world
text2: hello again
```

Unfortunately the console output in my browser is
`/static/media/data.a7c53baa.yaml` (the file path where the yaml file is located on the dev server) instead of the parsed content.

I expected a structure similar to `{"text":"hello world", "text2":"hello again"}` to be printed on the console.

What did I do wrong?